# Handlebars Partials and Grunt: partial cannot be found

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, handlebars.js, handlebarshelper

for my small single page app i'm using handlebars and Grunt.js in order to compile files.
I found a [grunt modules](https://github.com/koraysels/grunt-register-hbs-partials) which  scan a specified folder and generate a file with the specific Handlebars.registerPartial but when i compile my files I got

```
Uncaught Error: The partial templates/partials/footer could not be found
```

and I'm afraid i'm messing up with order to call different function but I cannot understand how it works.

My index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title> My app </title>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
  <script id="main-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">​
  <h1> Hello i'm the main </h1>

    {{> templates/partials/footer }}    

  </script>

    <script type="text/javascript" src="javascript/app.js"> </script> 
  </body>
</html>
```

My app.js

```
[here I include handlebars.js]
var ai = {};

(function () {
  // init part
  var source   = $("#main-template").html();
  var template = Handlebars.compile(source);
  $(document.body).append(template());

})();
```

And here is the generated file from the module which I don't include in my app.js

```
module.exports = function (Handlebars) {
    function setup() {
        Handlebars.registerPartial("templates/partials/footer", require("./templates/partials/footer.hbs"));
    }

    return {
        setup: setup
    };
};
```

Gruntfile.js:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-jshint');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-concat');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-register-hbs-partials');

  grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    jshint: {
    //check error in js files
      files: ['Gruntfile.js', 'javascript/scripts/*.js'],
      options: {
        globals: {
          jQuery: true
        }
      }
    },
    concat: {
    //concat js files
      options: {
        separator: '\n/**********/\n'
      },
      dist: {
        src: ['javascript/libs/*.js', 'javascript/scripts/*.js'],
        dest: 'javascript/app.js'
      }
    },
    uglify: {
    //minify js files
      dist: {
        files: {
          'javascript/app.min.js': ['javascript/app.js']
        }
      }
    },
    register_partials: {
      //register hbs files as hbs partials
      default_options: {
          options: {
              extension: '.hbs'
          },
          files: {
              'templates/partials_default.js': [ 'templates/partials/footer.hbs', 'templates/partials/header.hbs']
          },
      }
    },
    watch: {
      files: ['javascript/scripts/*.js'],
      tasks: ['jshint', 'register_partials']
    }
  });

  grunt.registerTask('dev', ['jshint', 'register_partials', 'concat', 'watch']);
  grunt.registerTask('prod', ['jshint', 'register_partials', 'concat', 'uglify']);

};
```

footer.hbs
 I'm the footer

File tree:

```
- Gruntfile.js
- packages.json
- index.html
- templates
      |_ partials
             |_ footer.hbs

- javascript 
        |_app.js
              |_ handlebars.js
              |_ scripts/init.js
```

Any help is reeeeally appreciated

Comment: You get the error when you run the grunt task?  Can you share the Gruntfile target configuration?

Comment: you are right @JamesWing, I updated with my Gruntfile.js. I also try again to use this module with test project basically empty and I still get this error. So I guess is soemthing in how the module is configured.

Comment: Are running Handlebars on the client or on the server?  I believe the grunt-register-hbs-partials library assumes that you are using Handlebars on the server, and generates a node.js module for use on the server.

Comment: mhm can be! I'm doing on client side actually

Comment: So the error message you get is from Grunt on the server, or from Handlebars on the client?  If you want to run Handlebars on the client, I believe you need to do something in you `app.js` to tell Handlebars to load your partials.  Where do you reference `partials_default.js` to cause it to be loaded?